# How to keep only one header row in output processing test using python and gnu-parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

#### The Problem

Often I need to process a directory of several CSV files and produce a single output file. Frequently, I rely on GNU parallel to run these tasks concurrently. However, I need a way to discard the first row (header) for all but the first job that returns output.

To make this concrete, imagine a directory of several CSV files like this...

```
x,y
1,1.2
2,5.3
3,6.0
```

Then, there's some (Python) script, call it `calc.py`, that cleans the data or does calculations...

```py
import csv
import math
import sys

rdr = csv.DictReader(sys.stdin)
wtr = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=['x', 'y', 'siny'])
wtr.writeheader()

for row in rdr:
    row['siny'] = math.sin(float(row['y']))
    wtr.writerow(row)
```

We can then process the data files in parallel with GNU parallel...

```
parallel --lb python calc.py '<' {} ::: $(ls -1 *.csv)
```

This, however, will produce multiple header rows. For example...

```
x,y,siny
1,1.2,0.9320390859672263
2,5.3,-0.8322674422239013
3,6.0,-0.27941549819892586
x,y,siny
4,7.2,0.7936678638491531
5,2.2,0.8084964038195901
6,0.9,0.7833269096274833
```

I am looking for a simple way (ideally an option to `parallel`) to only keep the first header line in the *output*. The stuff related to headers in the manual seems to be about inputs.

#### Possible Solutions

I see a few options, but I don't love any of them...

1. Don't have `calc.py` output the header and instead echo a header before running parallel. The disadvantage is that the header must be known or we need to peek at the header by running something like `python calc.py data1.csv | head -n 1` before running `parallel`.
2. Save the output of each job to a separate file, then concatenate them ex post (e.g. with `xsv`, `tail`, `sed`, etc.), removing the header from all but the first. This has the disadvantage of having to manage additional files on disk and clean them up afterwards.
3. Write another program that does this and pipe the results of `parallel` to that.

   - Seems CPU intensive to compare each line of output against the first line, and we know few records will match.
   - Assumes no valid data records match the header row.

What's the best way to solve this?
Is there an option that tells parallel to ignore all but one header row from each job's output?

Comment: I also tried to find a way to do using GNU parallel and was unable to find one. Was left with the types of options you listed.

Comment: Why not just loading the csv as data in python (which you are already doing) and merging using python capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adjusting option 1:

Make the program take two arguments: file jobnumber

```
if jobnumber == 1:
  output header
```

To guarantee that job 1 is printed first, use `--keep-order`:

```
parallel --keep-order python calc.py {#} '<' {} ::: *.csv
```

GNU Parallel will cache the output from the running jobs in /tmp to serialize the output, which may or may not be slower than `--lb`.

In general you can do something like:

```
parallel -k python 'calc.py < {} {= uq; $_ = seq()==1 ? "" : "| tail +2" =}' ::: *.csv
```

`uq` is available since 20190722.

You will be running a `tail`, so it can be slightly slower. On my system `tail` delivers 0.5 GB/s per core.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. It would be nice if this feature (retaining a single header) could make it into GNU parallel, however, to also solve the problem when using pre-existing tools (e.g. `xsv`).

Comment: Some existing tools, like GNU datamash, already take arguments indicating if the first line is a header and if it should be output. For GNU datamash these are `--header-in` and `--header-out`. If there's a way to convert the parallel `jobnumber` arg into the command line argument of an existing program it could be useful for some existing tools. Overall though, it would be definitely be nice have this functionality (retaining a single header) inside GNU parallel.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, GNU Parallel do not provide any such option to write header only once in output

But a simple approach can be to use `awk` to output header row only once like

```
parallel --lb python calc.py '<' {} ::: $(ls -1 *.csv) | awk 'NR==1 { header=$0; print $0; next; } $0 != header'
```

#### Explanation

`NR` is line number in awk. When line number is 1 it will store it in variable `header` and only print once. If any row exactly matched with header afterwards, it will be ignored

#### Pros

- You do not need to know the header beforehand
- You do not need to save output into separate files
- No need to change your code

#### Cons

- Assumes no data row exactly matches header
- In case there is no header present it will trim first line and all sames lines from output
- There is slight overhead of string matching

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll have to investigate how bad the overhead is.